# Commit to multiple SVN repositories (maybe using Git-SVN?)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I need to commit to multiple (3, one of them my own which I could change to GIT) Subversion repositories, what's the best way of doing this? Is Git-SVN applicable for that? I have seen that there is already a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239217/svn-commit-to-multiple-repositories), but I couldn't find a answer fitting my needs on it, also like already mentioned I have no problem using Git-SVN if this simplifies things.
I am using Eclipse, would be great if all things could be done from within it without writing scripts etc - but that's not mandatory, the primary thing I need is a way to commit to multiple SVN repositories. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Are all repositories in sync? Is it possible that a commit may fail, because there's conflict? Can you provide a typical workflow?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, it's not relevant for me anymore.

Comment: I have the same need... I disconnect and connect the the others repositories... not the best practice. How do you do it?

Comment: I gave up on this ;-)